# java.lang.NullPointerException - .onCreate - Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

I am creating a course application and when I am trying to open an existing Activity by clicking a button it gives me this error:

````
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
android.view.View android.widget.Button.findViewById(int)' on a null object 
reference at com.lorenzotribuiani.tailorin.HomePage.onCreate```
````

Does anybody know why?

here it is the java code:

```
/* code for creating a new Activity by clicking the btn */
    Button btnEmbrodery = findViewById(R.id.btn_embrodery);
    btnEmbrodery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(HomePage.this,EmbroderyTheoryActivity.class));
        }
    });
```

I really don't know why it goes like this...

Here it is the whole code about the java file:

```
public class HomePage extends AppCompatActivity {

private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);



 /* code for creating a new Activity by clicking the btn */
    Button btnEmbrodery = findViewById(R.id.btn_embrodery);
    btnEmbrodery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(HomePage.this,EmbroderyTheoryActivity.class));
        }
    });

DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
// Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
// menu should be considered as top level destinations.
mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
        R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
        .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
        .build();
NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    boolean logged = intent.getBooleanExtra("isLogged", false);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
     NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, mAppBarConfiguration)
             || super.onSupportNavigateUp();  } }
```

AndroidManifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/logo_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


 <activity
        android:name=".EmbroderyTheoryActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_embrodery_theory"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"></activity>
<activity
    android:name=".Registration"
    android:theme="@style/FirstRunLogin" />
<activity
    android:name=".FirstRun_Login"
    android:theme="@style/FirstRunLogin" />
<activity
    android:name=".HomePage"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
<activity
    android:name=".SplashScreen"
    android:theme="@style/SplashScreen">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: post up your whole code

Comment: you may missed setcontentview() before finding view

Comment: @Wini i've done that down belove

Comment: @TheCodersCompany your code i run my android studio..it is working fine ....onclick button it is taking me to next activity...have declare `EmbroderyTheoryActivity` in your `manifest`?

Comment: @Wini yes.. i've done that...wait check it down belove i'll add the manifest code

Comment: dont add in answer section...edit your question only

Comment: @Wini yes now i've done that

Comment: just comment your drawer code and oveeride methods and then run

Comment: @Wini but i've already added some comments in my code

Answer (score 0):

just run following code and comment all rest code and then run

the follwing code works for me

```
 public class MainActivity  extends AppCompatActivity {


//  private AppBarConfiguration mAppBarConfiguration;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

    // Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    // setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    /* code for creating a new Activity by clicking the btn */
    Button btnEmbrodery = findViewById(R.id.btn_embrodery)
      Btnembrodery. Setonclickliner{......
    Fragment fragment = CustomFragment.newInstance();

     FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

    ft.replace(R.id.container, fragmentObject);
    ft.commit();
        }
    });}}
```

Comment: `startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), EmbroderyTheoryActivity.class));`  have you used getapplicationContext() instead of `HomePage.this`????@TheCodersCompany

Comment: I forgot to tell you that i'm using a fragment page and not the normal one

Comment: means `EmbroderyTheoryActivity.class` is a fragment page/class? @TheCodersCompany

Comment: Yes, it is..
I've created a Menu Activity and ANdroid studio by himself has created the fragments, and in those fragment i put the layout

Comment: @TheCodersCompany  I updated answer.... Replace framlayout on clicklisterner